# Angular 4 & Ionic 3: Unable to populate Ionic menu from JSON file due to async nature of http.get() call

Tags: json, angular, asynchronous, ionic3

I am relatively new to Angular and my first project is building a mobile web app using the Ionic Framework. For whatever reason, my JSON file containing all the menu options is not being read into my App Component.

My menu_labels variable which is supposed to be an array of the JSON properties is returning as `undefined`, which means my *ngFor directive is getting skipped.

`<ion-list-header *ngFor="let item of menu_labels; let i of index" no-lines no-padding>`

After searching through many questions similar to this, I've determined that the issue is probably due to the HTTP request being async, and not returning in time to be used by my HTML doc. However, the fixes for them don't aren't working for my issue.

An excerpt of my JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"pages":[
    {
        "title": "Home",
        "component": "Homepage"
    },
    {
        "title": "News",
        "component": "NewsPage"
    },
    {
        "title": "Mainframe Legacy and Managed Hosting",
        "children": [
            {
                "title": "Mainframe Outsourcing",
                "component": "MainframeOutsourcing"
            },
.
.
.
```

I believe the problem is either in the way I use the `http.get()` function in my `MyApp` class of the **app.component.ts** file:

```
// Save the parsed information from http.get() in menu_labels var
menu_labels: any[];

constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar,
            public splashScreen: SplashScreen, private http: Http) {

  this.initializeApp();

  let menu_data = this.getData();
  menu_data.subscribe(data => {
      this.menu_labels = data;
    })
}

getData() {
    // parse information from json file containing menu structure
    return this.http.get('../assets/main-menu.json').map(res=> res.json().items);
}
```

Or in the way I try to handle the data being asynchronous in my **app.html** file:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <!-- First Level -->
      <ion-list-header *ngFor="let item of menu_labels; let i of index" no-lines no-padding>
        <!-- Just Add Button If No Children -->
        <ion-item *ngIf="!item.children" no-lines text-wrap>
          <button ion-item (click)="openPage(item.component)">{{ item.title }}</button>
        </ion-item>
.
.
.
```

I tried using `*ngIf` in the `<ion-list>` tag to handle the async call but the same result.

Can anyone tell me which part of my code the problem is in? I've been scratching my head over this for hours. I apologize in advance for any code that hurts to look at. This is also my first Angular project, so even though I took several courses on the basics I'm sure my implementation looks very ugly to someone more experienced.

Comment: Whats the output of this.menu_labels after data received?

Comment: Output is undefined when I log it to the console. However, I'm not sure how to check after data is received.

Comment: menu_data.subscribe(data => {
      this.menu_labels = data;
console.log(data);
    });

replace this.

Comment: Data prints undefined in console. Pretty sure it's an issue with getting the data from the JSON file now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue with this line ,

```
return this.http.get('./main-menu.json').map(res=> res.json().pages);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried your suggestion, but there is still no output in the menu. I believe the problem is before that line. Possibly with my *ngFor tag?

Comment: In that case try <ion-list *ngIf='menu_labels.length > 0'>

Comment: No luck. Also tried <ion-list *ngIf='menu_labels !== undefined'>. Your suggestion returned an error since menu_labels is undefined. Perhaps there is an issue in the way I use the http.get() or, more generally, how I'm accessing the JSON data?

Comment: Yes! You're updated answer populates the menu. I'm still getting errors when I try to click on an option, but that's way more progress than I've made all day. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisSterbenz, will you please also upvote the answer ?